# What is the most efficient way to detect if a string contains a number of consecutive duplicate characters in C#?

Tags: c#, string

For example, a user entered "I love this post!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"

the consecutive duplicate exclamation mark "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" should be detected.

Comment: How would you want to handle duplicates that are "correct," as in "I love this correct comment about terrible commas by tvanfosson?" See the problem?

Comment: @Glennular -- you should have just said "what about me?"

Comment: There can be some valid words having consecutive duplicates.

Comment: Are you interested in the longest consecutive sequence, all such sequences or just to know if such sequence exists ?

Comment: A more realistic example would be "omg I luv tihs post!!!!!!!!!!!1111"

Comment: Did any of these work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regular expression would detect repeating chars.  You could up the number or limit this to specific characters to make it more robust.

```
        int threshold = 3;
        string stringToMatch = "thisstringrepeatsss";
        string pattern = "(\\d)\\" + threshold + " + ";
        Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
        Match m = r.Match(stringToMatch);
        while(m.Success)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("character passes threshold " + m.ToString());
                m = m.NextMatch();
         }
```

Comment: @AngryHacker you edited the post but left the Java class names, there's no `Matcher` class in C# (BCL).

Comment: You can use a string literal for the regex: `"(\\w)\\1+"` --> `@"(\w)\1+"`. Also this answer is Java - use `Regex` and `regex.IsMatch` instead of `Pattern`

Comment: I tried this solution without any luck. Can you correct my method?
`static bool ContainsSuccessionOfSameCharacter(string textToCheck, int maxNumberOfConsecutiveDuplicates)
        {
            string pattern = @"(\w)\"+ maxNumberOfConsecutiveDuplicates +"+";
            var r = new Regex(pattern);
            Match m = r.Match(textToCheck);
            return m.Success;
        }        `

Answer (score 2):

Here's and example of a function that searches for a sequence of consecutive chars of a specified length and also ignores white space characters:

```
    public static bool HasConsecutiveChars(string source, int sequenceLength)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
            return false;
        if (source.Length == 1) 
            return false;

        int charCount = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            char c = source[i];
            if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
                continue;
            if (c == source[i+1])
            {
                charCount++;
                if (charCount >= sequenceLength)
                    return true;
            }
            else
                charCount = 1;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Edit fixed range bug :/

Answer (score 0):

The better way i my opinion is create a array, each element in array is responsible for one character pair on string next to each other, eg first aa, bb, cc, dd. This array construct with 0 on each element.

Solve of this problem is a for on this string and update array values.
You can next analyze this array for what you want.

Example: For string: bbaaaccccdab, your result array would be { 2, 1, 3 }, because 'aa' can find 2 times, 'bb' can find one time (at start of string), 'cc' can find three times.

Why 'cc' three times? Because 'cc'cc & c'cc'c & cc'cc'.

Comment: Baa! Aardvark's hate rubble. How did that streptococcus or pneumonoccus infect his coccyx? - 2,1,3. Granted, it's nonsense, but clearly still valid grammatically. (2, 1, 3, ...., 1, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in `O(n)` easily: for each character, if the previous character is the same as the current, increment a temporary count. If it's different, reset your temporary count. At each step, update your global if needed.

For `abbccc` you get:

```
a => temp = 1, global = 1
b => temp = 1, global = 1
b => temp = 2, global = 2
c => temp = 1, global = 2
c => temp = 2, global = 2
c => temp = 3, global = 3

=> c appears three times. Extend it to get the position, then you should be able to print the "ccc" substring.
```

You can extend this to give you the starting position fairly easily, I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution I crafted with some extra duplicates thrown in for good measure. As others pointed out in the comments, some duplicates are going to be completely legitimate, so you may want to narrow your criteria to punctuation instead of mere characters.

```
string input = "I loove this post!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!aa";

int index = -1;
int count =1;
List<string> dupes = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < input.Length-1; i++)
{
    if (input[i] == input[i + 1])
    {
        if (index == -1)
            index = i;

        count++;
    }
    else if (index > -1)
    {
        dupes.Add(input.Substring(index, count));
        index = -1;
        count = 1;
    }
}

if (index > -1)
{
    dupes.Add(input.Substring(index, count));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ! (For everything, not just this)

```
string test = "aabb";
return test.Where((item, index) => index > 0 && item.Equals(test.ElementAt(index)));
// returns "abb", where each of these items has the previous letter before it
```

OR

```
string test = "aabb";
return test.Where((item, index) => index > 0 && item.Equals(test.ElementAt(index))).Any();
// returns true
```