# Find the longest repetition character in String

Tags: c#, string

Let's say i have a string like

```
string text = "hello dear";
```

Then I want to determine the longest repetition of coherented characters - in this case it would be `ll`. If there are more than one with the same count, take any.

I have tried to solve this with linq

```
char rchar = text.GroupBy(y => y).OrderByDescending(y => y.Count()).Select(x => x).First().Key;
int rcount = text.Where(x => x == rchar).Count();
string routput = new string(rchar, rcount);
```

But this returns `ee`. Am I on the right track?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to detect if a string contains a number of consecutive duplicate characters in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671215/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-detect-if-a-string-contains-a-number-of-consec)

Comment: The problem with `GroupBy` is that you're counting the occurrences of each character _in the whole string_, whether they are contiguous or not. Since there's two `e` and they are the first character to appear twice in your text, `ee` is returned.

Comment: @wudzik - all those answers are outdated or require a sequenceLength / threshold - which is not given. probably the question is duplicate but your duplicate suggestion doesn't really provide a suitable answer

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault and is there a easy way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution using LINQ:

```
string text = "hello dear";
string longestRun = new string(text.Select((c, index) => text.Substring(index).TakeWhile(e => e == c))
                                   .OrderByDescending(e => e.Count())
                                   .First().ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(longestRun); // ll
```

It selects a sequence of substrings starting with the same repeating character, and creates the result string with the longest of them.

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer doing things with LINQ, you can do it fairly simply with a LINQ extension:

```
var text = "hello dear";
var result = string.Join("",
    text
    .GroupAdjacentBy((l, r) => (l == r)) /* Create groups where the current character is 
                                         Is the same as the previous character */
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()) //Order by the group lengths
    .First()                           //Take the first group (which is the longest run)
);
```

With this extension (taken from [Use LINQ to group a sequence of numbers with no gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681949/use-linq-to-group-a-sequence-of-numbers-with-no-gaps)):

```
public static class LinqExtensions 
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupAdjacentBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
    {
        using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (e.MoveNext())
            {
                var list = new List<T> { e.Current };
                var pred = e.Current;
                while (e.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (predicate(pred, e.Current))
                    {
                        list.Add(e.Current);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        yield return list;
                        list = new List<T> { e.Current };
                    }
                    pred = e.Current;
                }
                yield return list;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Might be a bit overkill - but I've found `GroupAdjacentBy` quite useful in other situations as well.

Answer (score 4):

Although a regex or custom Linq extension is fine, if you don't mind "doing it the old way" you can achieve your result with two temporary variables and a classic `foreach` loop.

The logic is pretty simple, and runs in O(n). Loop through your string and compare the current character with the previous one.

If it's the same, increase your `count`. If it's different, reset it to `1`.

Then, if your `count` is greater than the previous recorded max count, overwrite the `rchar` with your current character.

```
string text = "hello dear";

char rchar = text[0];
int rcount = 1;

int currentCount = 0;
char previousChar = char.MinValue;
foreach (char character in text)
{
    if (character != previousChar)
    {
        currentCount = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        currentCount++;
    }

    if (currentCount >= rcount)
    {
        rchar = character;
        rcount = currentCount;
    }

    previousChar = character;
}

string routput = new string(rchar, rcount);
```

It's indeed verbose, but gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

RegEx would be a option

```
string text = "hello dear";
string Result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? string.Empty : Regex.Matches(text, @"(.)\1*", RegexOptions.None).Cast<Match>().OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).First().Value;
```